# Gridview with smoothscroll, problems with big images

Tags: android, image, listview, smooth-scrolling

I created a main layout where I can disable the scroll and set this code for scroll in 2 different listviews when I scroll on main activity.

The problem is than one activity has a small image and if scroll inside this image, main activity scroll the other listview, but the listview with the image is stuck like free scroll, what can I do?

Here is my code scroll:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
  switch (event.getAction())
  {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   //the user places his finger on the screen
      mLastY=(int)event.getY();
      Log.d("posicion",String.valueOf(pos));//to get the "y" position starting
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      if(mLastY-event.getY() > 50) //if a movement of the size of an item occurs
      {
        if(pos+1<arrayeventos.size())
        {
          pos=pos+1;

          Log.d("posicion ARRIBA",String.valueOf(pos));
          //listView.invalidate();
          // mLastY=(int)event.getY();   //reset the starting position to the current position
          //vestimentaicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.casualm);

          //             setter.putall(pos);

          listView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
          gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(4*pos);

          mLastY=(int)event.getY();
        }
      }
```

Comment: I was going to edit the question, as it presently makes little sense, however I have no idea what you are asking. Please try to improve the question.

Comment: Thanks, i try it. When i do the scroll gesture inside a small imagebutton, the listview wich contains this image dosen't scroll, by the other hand the other listview was scrolled good.

Comment: Please try to compose your question with little more sense. I can't understand your question.

Comment: when i scroll inside an image of a listview, this scroll code dosen't work good. inside the image, i can scroll like a free view in the listview, and this code it's for go to X position

Comment: OK so I still do not understand, maybe try pictures?

Comment: ok i found the problem. i descativate the scroll in the listview, but i can still scroll this one if i click on an image, how can i unable the scroll inside an image in a listview with adapter?